# Unable to reference function in a javascript file created using browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I created a JavaScript file using browserify library. the generated file looks like this:

```
(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);throw new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'")}var f=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(f.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},f,f.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){
this.showResult = function () {
        return 'result';
  };
},{}]},{},[1])
```

I used `browserify myfile.js > newFile.js` command file to create file.

This file contains `showResult` function. Now I have added reference to this file in my index.htm page. When I am trying to reference the function I am getting `0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'showResult' is undefined` error.

How can I reference any function into page?

Answer (score 0):

```
var ctx = {};

(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);throw new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'")}var f=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(f.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},f,f.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){
    this.showResult = function () {
        alert("showResult was called!");
    };
},{}]},ctx,[1])

ctx['1'].exports.showResult();
```

Comment: Can you please explain what is going on here ? I assume you modify the file manually. I think the file should be useable as soon as you generate it.

Comment: Your functionality is grouped into modules which you have to declare. So you can make use of require etc. For detailed information have a look at: http://browserify.org/

Comment: @skjm: I don't understand. Am I Suppose to modify the file as you have done or this should happen out of the box?

Comment: Yes of course this should happen out of the box. Please have a look into the documentation. I'm shure there are options to define everything. (https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#usage)